# prometheus SNMP Exporter generator: go build permission denied

Tags: prometheus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQNwF.png)

I already installed generator for SNMP exporter with followed some steps from this website (https://sbcode.net/prometheus/snmp-exporter-generator/), yet it mentioned that 'open snmp_exporter:permission denied' (I already installed snmp exporter and in status 'actived'
how to fix this?

(it mentioned in previous question box)